# How to use a virtualenv from inside a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using a jupyter notebook, and **inside** this running jupyter notebook I want to use a virtualenv.

I was able to create and source(?) a virtualenv by using these commands

```
!virtualenv venv
!. venv/bin/activate
```

but it looks like `python` is still being used from the standard location

```
!which python
/opt/conda/bin/python
```

Is there any way to create and switch virtual environments from **inside** a running jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 3):

After activating the `venv`

```
pip install ipykernel
ipython kernel install --user --name=venv
jupyter notebook
```

In jupyter Notebook you would be able to choose between `venv` and `python x`.

Comment: sorry, you did not understand. The jupyter notebook is already running. I cannot stop the jupyter notebook - it is already running. I want to chang the environment from WITHIN the running jupyter notebook. I CANNOT go 'out' and restart the jupyter notebook. It is already running!

Comment: I am sorry, I missed the "running" part.